# android keypad back button overriding password activity

Tags: android, password-protection, back-button

I have a problem regarding the back button on the android keypad.

I have a main activity with a button, "Enter" that leads to another activity, Activity 2. Now I have password to protect Activity 2, so that when the button "Enter" is presseed a password prompt is shown to check input against stored password. Simple.

Now if I were to leave Activity 2 and return to the main activity, and then i pressed the back button on the keypad, the password prompt does not show up and Activity 2 is accessed. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Please let me know if I was not clear, and I do not think the code need showing here.

Comment: Yes, you do need to show your code. There are dozens of ways to implement what you are trying to achieve, and without seeing what you did right, there's no way to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: @user1742524 Write finish() in activity2's onBackPressed() method.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onPause() method in your activity.  Include some code that destroys the log in credentials

Override onResume() in your activity to test for the credentials. Probably something similar to what you did in onCreate().

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to understand the life cycle of an Activity in Android.